# Extend array modal editor

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is it possible to extend the array modal dialog without overwriting the array-modal.js (apostrophe-schemas/public/js)?

I'm trying to create a link array in the global module, for that i created:

```
...
name: 'links',
label: 'Links',
type: 'array',
titleField: 'title',
schema: [{
  name: 'title',
  label: 'Title',
  type: 'string'
}, {
  name: 'url',
  label: 'Url',
  type: 'url'
}, {
  name: '_page',
  label: 'Page',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'apostrophe-page',
  idField: 'pageId',
  filter: {
    projection: {
      title: 1,
      slug: 1
    }
  }
}]
...
```

Now i want to set the title field and disable the url field if a Page is
selected. Or use the title and url field.
If i register a script like this:

```
apos.define('apostrophe-array-editor-modal', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-modal',
  source: 'arrayEditor',
  ...
});
```

i overwrite the orginal array-modal.js, but i only want to register a change handler and check the inputs before save.

My goal is a list of (footer/static) links the admin can edit in the global section and i can use them in several pages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to make some sort of `type` field for each link where the editor makes a choice between an internal page join and an external URL.

`select` schema fields have a `showFields` parameter that can hide/show parts of a schema form based on the selection made, check out the documentation here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-select-code

Your code would look something like

```
  name: 'links',
  label: 'Links',
  type: 'array',
  titleField: 'title',
  schema: [{
    name: 'title',
    label: 'Title',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'linkType',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Type',
    choices: [{
      label: 'External',
      value: 'external',
      showFields: ['url']
    }, {
      label: 'Internal',
      value: 'internal',
      showFields: ['_page']
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'url',
    label: 'Url',
    type: 'url'
  }, {
    name: '_page',
    label: 'Page',
    type: 'joinByOne',
    withType: 'apostrophe-page',
    idField: 'pageId',
    filter: {
      projection: {
        title: 1,
        slug: 1
      }
    }
  }]
```

In your template you can always check the value of `linkType` to make markup decisions.

Comment: thanks, this will solve my problem. But is it possible to load two or more js-files for one modal dialog. Or is it possible to load a js-file/s for a specific field?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're trying to do but you can load custom js in an piece's editor modal by overriding the `beforeShow` method in the piece's `editor-modal.js`

Documentation here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/extending-the-pieces-editor-modal.html